# Detect second click in .setOnItemClickListener()

Tags: java, android, android-listview, onitemclicklistener

How can I detect when the listview item has been clicked a second time?

I have made it so that when an item in the listview is clicked, the color is set to green. Now what I want is the color to change back on a second click.

Can anyone explain how I can do so?

Heres where I set the color green:

```
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){  
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id){

            parent.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

        }
    });
```

Comment: Check background color when item click base on set other background color.

Comment: Thats only a suggestion depending on what you want to do at the end, but you can do some type of counter, then in the inItemCLick, just watch how many clicks has been made, and change the color in function of that. probably will be some way that would be better than this, but meanwhile you can move foward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an attribute variable in your Listener. Like this:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
    private Set<Integer> hasClickedSet = new HashSet<Integer>();
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id){
        if (hasClickedSet.contains(position)){
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        } else {
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            hasClickedSet.add(position);
        }
}
```

and you need not calling parent.getChildAt(position). Just use the 'v' parameter.

========EDIT============
ok, try this:

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
        private SparseArray<Boolean> hasClicked = new SparseArray<Boolean>();
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id){
            if (hasClicked.get(position, false)){
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                hasClicked.put(position, false);
            } else {
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                hasClicked.put(position, true);
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are trying to modify anything from your cell it not gonna work for the second click.
For that, try to make your listener inside your adapter and then change the color of the background (convertView.setBackground(*)). For me it works like below:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

  convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      if (viewHolder.addedButton.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
        viewHolder.addedButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        convertView.setBackground(any_color_you_want);
        listener.onButtonAdd(v, position);
      } else {
        viewHolder.addedButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        convertView.setBackground(any_color_you_want);
        listener.onButtonRemove(v, position);
      }
    }
  });

}
```

In this example, I was trying to do a checkable list.

Answer (score 2):

Try this way

```
  Boolean flag=false;

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){  
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id){

            if(flag==false){
            parent.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            flag=true;
            }
            else{
            parent.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            flag=false;
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Excellent! Exactly the type of solution I was going for. Thank you!

Comment: Except that I have to tap the item twice. Whats up with that?

Comment: You should had more than one flag. Use a SparseArray to store flags of each item view.

Answer (score 0):

You can track n number of click

```
     int count = 0; // define globally
    view.clickListener(){
         count++;
         if (count==1)
            {
              // first click
            }
         else{
              // not first click
              }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

Take HashMap which hold all position and Boolean for is click or not :

```
HashMap<Integer,Boolean> clickMap = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
```

Check HashMap contain this position mean this position item clicked base on change background as well Boolean value in HashMap :

```
if(clickMap.containsKey(position) && clickMap.get(position)){
    parent.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.orignal);
    clickMap.put(position,false);
}else{
    clickMap.put(position,true);
    parent.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
}
```